# How do I get the programme to print out the receipt format with the correct subtotal?

Tags: python-3.x

thanks so much for the help. I want to print out the orders in this format:

```
85791008     Mango-1           £1     3    £3
86139113    Strawberries-500g  £1.50  2    £3
Total cost of order:                       £6
```

This is my code:

```
import csv

option='yes'
user_orders=[]
final_price=0.00

while option=='yes':
    data=open('Product information.csv', 'rt')
    purchase=csv.reader(data)
    order=input('Please enter the GTIN-8 code of the product you would like to purchase: ')
    for row in purchase:
        for field in row:
            if order in field:
                quantity=int(input('How much of that item: '))
                final_price=quantity*float(row[2]) + final_price
                receipt=('{} {} {} {} {}'.format(row[0]+'     ', row[1]+'     ', str(quantity)+'     ', "{:10.2f}".format(float(row[2]))+'     ', "{:10.2f}".format(quantity * float(row[2]))))
                user_orders.append(receipt)
                print('You have added '+(receipt))
                option=input('Would you like to add another iem to your order, yes or no: ')
                if option=='no':
                    for user_order in user_orders:
                        print('\n' + user_order)
                    print('\nTotal cost of order:                                                 '+ "{:10.2f}".format(final_price))
```

How do you edit this to print out in the format at the top?

Comment: Move the last print statement out of the loop, like it's shown on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you've declared default vars inside the loop and they reset on every iteration (final_price, user_orders). Apart from this, the formatting was messed up and you've used int type for the prices, which is not a good idea. There was an error when the price in the csv file has a floating point.

```
import csv

option='yes'
user_orders=[]
final_price=0.00

while option=='yes':
    data=open('Product information.csv', 'rt')
    purchase=csv.reader(data)
    order=input('Please enter the GTIN-8 code of the product you would like to purchase: ')
    for row in purchase:
        for field in row:
            if order in field:
                quantity=int(input('How much of that item: '))
                final_price=quantity*float(row[2]) + final_price
                receipt=('{} {} {} {} {}'.format(row[0]+'     ', row[1]+'     ', str(quantity)+'     ', "{:10.2f}".format(float(row[2]))+'     ', "{:10.2f}".format(quantity * float(row[2]))))
                user_orders.append(receipt)
                print('You have added '+(receipt))
                option=input('Would you like to add another iem to your order, yes or no: ')
                if option=='no':
                    for user_order in user_orders:
                        print('\n' + user_order)
                    print('\nTotal cost of order:                                                 '+ "{:10.2f}".format(final_price))
```

Comment: Hi Nikolay, thanks for the help, but your code doesn't print out the final subtotal. :(

Comment: Hi Nikolay, I really appreciate the help. If you read the original question at the top. It explains a new problem.

Comment: Nikolay, thank you sooo much!! By any chance, do you know how to align the receipt, so all the prices are aligned.